# SugarCRM: Adding a variable to the session on user login

Tags: session, sugarcrm

I need to add some information to the session upon user login. Where is the best place to do this in SugarCRM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at extending SugarAuthenticate authentication class (see in modules/Users/authentication for examples) and override postLoginAuthenticate() method (don't forget to call the parent one!). You may also use after_login logic hook which is called on successful login.